# WPF MVVM UserControl Binding to create a Wizard UI

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, mvvm

I m working in a WPF MVVM Project and I am using one Wpf Window. In this window i have a space for one usercontrol and two buttons next and back. When i click the next button I want usercontrol1 to be replaced with usercontrol2. etc.

Comment: You need wizard functionality like this - [MVVM Wizard for WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51804137/3601887)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you're trying to create a wizard-style user interface.

This [Code Project article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/InternationalizedWizard.aspx?display=Print) may help. And [right here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=wpf+wizard) is a good place for getting started too.

Answer (score 1):

You can have `Wizard` user control which is binded to `WizardModel`, In the `Wizard` control put `ContentPresenter` control, and bind it to `WizardModel's WizardPage` property. And by changing that `WizardPage` property, you can change wizard page from model.

Hope this helps, [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) used the same mechanism for changing views

Comment: HI ArsenMkrt te example is very good in hv used it but , it hvn't follow the MVVM pattern fully becoz, they used ViewModel Datatemplate in View Bt i think it is against MVVM Pattern 
 see in CoffeeWizardView.xaml

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:WelcomePageViewModel}">
      <view:WelcomePageView />
    </DataTemplate>