# C# WPF Multi Display

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

Alright so doing some WPF programming, which I don't do often... And I need to have like, on the main page I have 2 buttons, and each button is going to hide the main page and display a different page of controls.

I'm currently using ContentControl, and showing/hiding them as needed. And it's starting to get messy.
And I'm sure there's a better way to do this.

So... Suggestions =]?

EDIT: Sorry about it being vague, what I currently have is 2 buttons in a ContentControl, when clicking one of the buttons it hides that ContentControl, and shows a different ContentControl, with its own set of controls, and a back button. When clicking that back button it hides the current ContentControl, and shows the original. And this is getting messy, so im looking for a better method of doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you take a look at some MVC type of framework. They are design pattern solutions for problems just like the one you are describing.

The framework that I like most, because it's simple to understand and learning curve is not so steep is the [MVVM Light Toolkit](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/), but there is also [PRISM](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/) and [Caliburn](http://caliburn.codeplex.com/).

They might seem a little bit more complicated, but the clarity and organization it promotes in your code will pay off in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is rather vague.

You should probably make two user controls and hide/show them when clicking the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

That navigation concept is generally known a "Wizard". There are several wizard controls that you can use. There are several vendors with commercial WPF wizard controls, as well as several free versions, such as [here](http://pwlodek.blogspot.com/2008/11/wpf-wizard-control.html) and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/wizarddialog.aspx).

This is a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287193/is-there-a-wizard-control-in-wpf), also.

Answer (score 0):

Because what you are doing is limited in design, why not go with a DataTemplateSelector.

Based off the datacontext you can switch out the xaml being used.

[MSDN: DataTemplateSelector Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector.aspx)