# What is the best way to make a wizard using native WPF controls

Tags: wpf, wizard

I'm new to WPF and never happened the need for me to create a wizard in WPF. I want to know what control to use to make a simple wizard in WPF that I can collect information on each page and finalize an operation in the last page(step). I actually want to make it using native WPF controls. I don't know, like using page navigations or so. Any native wpf ideas?

Comment: Have a look here for the navigation part (wizard): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/287193/is-there-a-wizard-control-in-wpf

Comment: If you don't want to use a prebuilt one then your best bet is to start building your own and then come to StackOverflow when you have a specific question, rather than asking StackOverflow how to get started.  Your questions (both of them!) are too vague to be answered here since they lack specific detail, and there are many possible answers.

Comment: @DanPuzey Thanks, I know the question is basic and I specifically asked it, but I don't care how basic it is. Asking questions is not bad but you missed the idea of questioning here. I can invest lots of time researching, but when I can ask someone to show me a shortcut way then I don't have to waste my time and can get to the point directly and invest my time on other important things. I'm sure if someone is professional enough can show me directly what I want with just one solution!. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @Jahan: You have been shown a solution, and you've turned it down! Perhaps if you would explain your requirements in detail and why the WPF Extended Kit isn't suitable, you would get a better answer. Otherwise, the best answer you are likely to get is to go to Codeplex and copy & paste the WPF Extended toolkit code - which is, after all, built with WPF native controls.

Comment: @DanPuzey The reason is just to have full control over it in the development/maintenance phase. Actually I don't need detailed explanations. I just needed a starting point since it's been only 3 weeks that I've learnt WPF and have not that much experience in using all the controls. I think I'm going to use popup control with the page navigation. This is the only thing that have come to my mind up to now and wanted to know if any other have a better idea or if it's fine tell me just what I wanted to use is a smart solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make use of Tab Control for making a wizard.

For moving to the next screen on a particular index can bind the SelectedIndex property of the tab control to a property in the view model and if you do not wish to display the tab items in UI can set its height to 0.

Answer (score 4):

Check out the WPF Extended toolkit. It has a built in Wizard control.

[Wizard](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Wizard)

Comment: Thanks moncada, But I actually want to make it using native WPF controls.